sudo: unable to resolve host: Name or service not known
I noticed that in my team's Docker CI sudo commands, e.g. time sudo xvfb-run coverage run -m pytest test/gui, report an error such as:
sudo: unable to resolve host runner-qwqjblm--project-1351-concurrent-1: Name or service not known

Where runner-qwqjblm--project-1351-concurrent-1 is my the hostname of the instance, i.e.
$ cat /etc/hostname
runner-qwqjblm--project-1351-concurrent-1

$ hostname
runner-qwqjblm--project-1351-concurrent-1

From my research, problems such as this seem to stem from an ill-configured /etc/hosts file. Mine looks like this:
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.1  host.docker.internal

Other than the hostname not appearing in the file I don't know what is wrong and how exactly to fix it.
None of the recommendations that I've found in my search seem to fit this pattern.

Is this question about GitLab CI?

No just an Ubuntu image on Docker.

Ok, the question mentions "Docker CI" and `runner-[…]-project-[…]-concurrent-1* is a name from a runner of GitLab CI, so this looks like it is in fact run by GitLab CI.

Please Edit the question and add the steps before time sudo xvfb-run coverage run -m pytest test/gui. If you use a Dockerfile, add its content in the question. How did you end up with a container with the name runner-qwqjblm--project-1351-concurrent-1? How do you connect to it?

I found it here: Just append the name runner-qwqjblm--project-1351-concurrent-1 to first line of /etc/hosts and make it
127.0.0.1   localhost runner-qwqjblm--project-1351-concurrent-1

That did the trick for me.
